# Creating resource in WPF and binding its value to another resource

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

In WPF you can create new resource and bind its value to another resource if type it exposes public setter like so:

```
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="PrimaryBrush">#000000</SolidColorBrush>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="SecondaryBrush" Color="{Binding Color, Source={StaticResource PrimaryBrush}}"/> <!-- this works because SolidColorBrush exposes public Color prop -->
```

Is it possible to do the same for types that do not expose public property? For example:

```
<Duration x:Key="PrimaryDuration">00:00:01.500</Duration>
<Duration x:Key="SecondaryDuration">
  <Binding Source="{StaticResource PrimaryDuration}"/> <!-- The type 'Duration' does not support direct content -->
</Duration>
```

Comment: That's because you pass XAML object `Binding` instead of time value. Duration can be only constructed based on time content, not `Binding`.

Comment: Why would you need to do this?

Comment: I want to use ```ValueConverter``` on that ```SecondaryDuration``` for instance and use it multiple times in my ControlTemplate. With derived static resource based on the original resource converter will execute only once. For example with SolidColorBrush I can do something like this: ```<SolidColorBrush x:Key="SecondaryBrush" Color="{Binding Color, Source={StaticResource PrimaryBrush}, Converter={StaticResource MakeOpaque}}"/>``` and reuse ```SecondaryBrush``` in my template without hitting MakeOpaque more than once.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to do the same for types that do not expose public property?

Short answer: No, it's not because you can only bind to dependency properties like `Color`.

`Duration` is an immutable value type that must be constructed with a *compile-time* `TimeSpan` value.